# Appending TimeStamp in log file name of Java util logger

Tags: java, java.util.logging

Currently I am using using Java util for logging logs into the file which can be configured from `java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern`. I want to append a timestamp in the log file name. I also have to take the log file path from `java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern` property.

Comment: I hope you're using slf4j as a logging facade?

Comment: Use log4j :) and few more chars to satisfy minimum.

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse the FileHandler from Tomcat, it timestamps the filename and rolls it every day:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/7.0.x/java/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.java

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String currentTimestamp() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    return f.format(c.getTime());
}
```

this gives you back a timestamp

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this [post](http://javablog.co.uk/2008/07/12/logging-with-javautillogging/), explain logging in details.

You can use `%t` for time in your config file.

Comment: Link no longer exists.  java.util.logging.FileHandler does not support %t

Comment: That's even the temp directory now (/tmp)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html says: "%t" the system temporary directory